# How to get PHP simple XML value with child node?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML as shown. I Need to iterate through the  tags with for each loop and pull out the attributes `attr1`. But I'm constantly getting `"Illegal string offset"`.

My data:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <ID attr1="123" attr2="567">abc</ID>
    <ID attr1="123" attr2="567">abc</ID>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

My code:

```
foreach ($parentNode->Child->ID as $IDChild => $value)
{
    echo $value; // does this output "abc"?
    echo $IDChild['attr1']; // need to display "123", but throwing error.
    $IDChild['attr1'] = "999"; // also need to update the value in the xml
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$oXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Parent>
  <Child>
    <ID attr1="123" attr2="567">abc</ID>
    <ID attr1="123" attr2="567">abc</ID>
  </Child>
</Parent>');

foreach($oXml->Child->ID as $oXml)
    var_dump((string)$oXml['attr1']);
```